# Can't source some attributes from a webpage

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I've written a script in `php` to source some items from a webpage. However, when I execute my script, It doesn't fetch anything.

I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. Any help to fix this will be highly appreciated.

[Link to the site address](https://pokemondb.net/evolution)

The contents I look for are in `title` attributes within the following html blocks:

```
<ul class="list-nav panel panel-nav">
<li class="list-nav-title">Jump to</li>
<li><a title="Red/Blue/Yellow" href="#evo-g1">Generation 1</a></li>
<li><a title="Gold/Silver/Crystal" href="#evo-g2">Generation 2</a></li>
<li><a title="Ruby/Sapphire/FireRed/LeafGreen/Emerald" href="#evo-g3">Generation 3</a></li>
<li><a title="Diamond/Pearl/Platinum/HeartGold/SoulSilver" href="#evo-g4">Generation 4</a></li>
<li><a title="Black/White/Black 2/White 2" href="#evo-g5">Generation 5</a></li>
<li><a title="X/Y/Omega Ruby/Alpha Sapphire" href="#evo-g6">Generation 6</a></li>
<li><a title="Sun/Moon/Ultra Sun/Ultra Moon" href="#evo-g7">Generation 7</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is what I've tried so far with:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://pokemondb.net/evolution';

function curlGet($link){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $html;
}

$html_response = curlGet($url);
$html_doc = new DOMDocument();
@$html_doc->loadHTML($html_response);   
$content_xpath = new DOMXPath($html_doc);

$item_row = $content_xpath->query('//ul[contains(@class,"panel-nav")]//li/a/@title');
foreach($item_row as $file){
    $item_name = $file->nodeValue . "<br/>";
    echo $item_name;
}
?>
```

My expected output are like (they are within `title` attributes):

```
Red/Blue/Yellow
```

and so on----

Comment: The site redirects to HTTPS. `CURL` doesn't follow redirects by default, but we change that by setting `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to true. Also, when using `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` you shouldn't include `'User-Agent:'` in the string - just use `'Mozilla/5.0'`. If you apply those changes, you should have the required results. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, it did solve the problem.